# How can I change the size of an image when I drag the image up or down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi every one i am a beginner in programming.
 I want to change the size of an image when I drag the image up and down on my web page?
The size should decrease when i drag it up an increase when i drag it down.
I am able to change its size by animation now i want it to happen when i drag it.
Here's the code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div.hidden
{
width:20px;
height:80px;
background:white;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
left:50px;
top:400px;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s ; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from  {background:white; height:0px;width:0;left:50px; top:40px; }

to {background:white; height:80px;width:20px;left:50px; top:430px;}

}
</style>
</head>
<body background="road.jpg">
<div style="position:relative;width:126px;height:350px; overflow:hidden; border: solid             1px;left:639px;top:307px;">
<div class="hidden";></div>
</div>

To: <input type="text" name ="To"><br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a ready to use example but it is the idea that will help you..

```
var dragging = false;
$('img').mousedown(function(){
   dragging = true; // Detect if we are dragging the image
});

$(document).mousemove(function(){
    if(dragging === true) {
       $('img').height(event.pageY + 'px'); // Detect how many pixels high from the top of the screen
    }
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
   dragging = false; // detect when we are done
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4pFnQ/)

To get this working on your site or something instead of using `event.pageY` you will probably have to do some calcualtions with the `height` of the image, the `position` of the image and try and work out how many pixels you need to add or remove from the image.